# Passing float * and FILE * to/from functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, floating-point, void-pointers

First, I declare variables before the main() function:

```
// Files
FILE *density_model_file;
char *density_model_filename;
float *density_array;
```

Next, I open the FILE * for reading and allocate memory for the density array:

```
density_model_file = open4read(density_model_filename, program_name);
density_array = allocator(density_model_size, sizeof(float));
```

Up to this point, the debugger shows everything is working fine. Here
is the step that I can't seem to fix, where I am attempting to load
data into the calloc'd array:

```
density_array = floatfromfile(sizeof(float), density_model_size, density_model_file, density_model_filename);
```

The density_array has a NULL value after this step for some reason.
Here is the code for this function (contained in a separate .c file).
I have bolded the part where I think the issue exists:

```
float * floatfromfile(unsigned long int entrysize, int numentries, FILE *inputfile, const char *filename)
        {
        /* Declaration of density model array size variable */
    int numbytes;

    **void *temparray = 0;
    /* Writes the gravity model to file */
    numbytes = (int)fread(temparray, entrysize, numentries, inputfile);**


    /* Checks that the forward model file has a sufficient number of entries */
    if (numbytes == numentries)
        {
        printf("loaded %i values from %s using fread()\n", numbytes, filename);
        return((float *)temparray);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("ERROR: %i data points read from %s of %i needed\n", numbytes, filename, numentries);
        return((float *)temparray);
        }
    }
```

Any insight would be much appreciated. I think the issue might be that calloc() returns a pointer to a void array. I can provide the other functions if needed.

Comment: Bolding doesn't work inside code blocks. You may want to mark those lines differently, e.g. with comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fread` expects to be able to write its results into an allocated memory block. But you're giving it `temparray` which has not been allocated—in fact its value is 0. So you're giving `fread` the address 0 to write into, which is likely to cause the program to crash.  Instead you need to pass your allocated pointer `density_array` at this point.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a misunderstanding about how pointers work. What you need to do is pass `density_array` into `floatfromfile` as an argument.

What you are doing instead is overwriting the pointer to your allocated memory, with the return value from `floatfromfile`. That return value is always `NULL` because that's what you assigned it to (as `temparray`).